# Problema na importação no Flask (Unable to import 'controllers' pylint(import-error)

Tags: python, mvc, flask, importação

Boa noite, estou começando a programar agora e estou tentando fazer um sistema simples usando o framework Flask, porém durante a organização dos arquivos me deparei com o problema do título, não estou conseguindo importar o default localizado na pasta controllers, onde que eu estou errando?[image: organização do sistema e onde o erro de import está aparecendo]

Answer (score 0):

Basicamente o problema é porque você não está utilizando '.'
Existem duas opções possíveis para resolver o seu problema.

1. Importar um único arquivo:

```
from .controller import default
```

2. Importar todos os módulos do diretório

```
from . import controller
```